# How setup big data tools plugin for Intellij Idea to connect aws zeppeling notebook?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-zeppelin

I have seup a zeppeling notebook which **works** via web browser. E.g. I can connect and execute any queries. But when I tried to conenct via Intellij idea I got a message:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer of this plugin. Thank you that you are interested in our products.
To connect please remove `/notebook` suffix from the URL. You need put in the field clean URL, like `http://localhost:8080`.